# Second time I've ended up with my answer becoming double-posted. What might be happening here?

Tags: discussion

My comment on this [phantom/imposter answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25669/12102) says:

> This is the **second time** this has happened to me, a second, identical copy of my answer appears, and I seem to be open and active when I return to this tab. I see it open, and click save before noticing that it is a phantom/imposter post. In this case I was in the review cue (sic, it's "queue") in another tab at the same time, though I'm not sure if that's related.

I'm using the Chrome browser with several tabs open, but I am now *absolutely sure* that I never clicked the `Add Another Answer` button.

I thought I'd posted a question here the first time it happened to me, but I don't see it now. I'll see if I relocate the first double-answer (roughly a year ago).

**question:** How to make sure this doesn't happen again? It's not at all a major problem, I don't notice any adverse effects besides the poor aesthetics/optics of having a second, deleted answer.

I haven't added the `bug` tag yet since I'd like get to the bottom of what's actually happening. The `bug` tag can sometimes attract a `status-bydesign` labeler, who might clear up bugs by finding a plausible rationalization for the behavior, and thereby "solve" the issue prematurely.

**edit:** I remember that when I tried to save the phantom/imposter answer, I was presented with a Captcha and asked if I was a robot. I hadn't logged out during that brief span, so I'm not sure why. *I believe* that I dispensed with it by reloading the page. I can't remember exactly, but I didn't engage with it.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I really don't want to invoke the special `bug` tag until I am sure I haven't somehow done something inadvertently to cause this behavior. I know it will attract more attention, but that attention sometimes results in simply "no, it's not a bug" and the `status-bydesign` label, which then terminates the attention with some degree of finality. See for example [I don't understand why - by design - “ion-thruster” tag remains hidden when I start typing “ion…”](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/766/12102). This is not a burning issue, so there's no need to escalate quickly.

Comment: **update:** this may have [happened](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1015/12102) to someone else as well.