# "Serial Voting Reversal" unwarranted?

Tags: discussion

I just had a fairly large rep loss due to a serial vote reversal.

I don't see the kind of pattern I'd expect for this.

I've been answering a fair amount of questions lately about shuttle.

Is is possible the algorithm erred?

Comment: for those who haven't seen it personally, combined, OrganicMarble and my rep-deltas today exceeds 1,000.

Comment: I'd suggest asking on the mother meta about this, or just flag one of your own posts to ask a mod to look into it (or have them escalate it to SE staff).

Comment: What's the 'mother meta'?

Comment: @OrganicMarble https://meta.stackexchange.com/ have a look at [my doh!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324104/303080) while you're there

Comment: The most plausible guess is that someone deliberately serially upvoted you which is prohibited on SE. You're not in fault, but that user is.

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm not sure the algorithm can always distinguish "deliberately serial" voting from "highly/overly enthusiastic and reckless" voting. Either way it's good that it's detected and reversed, and hopefully discouraged/prevented. I've seen this a few times: [-30](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1009/12102), and [-300, -175, -605](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1064/12102). So far only small reversals for user removed, so hopefully it's a different person each time.

Comment: @Muze it looks like you had a reversal of [-60](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/18879/muze?tab=reputation) as well, meaning the algorithm detected someone up voting your posts in a serial fashion as well and reversed them. I am not sure why you say "[I think some of it was my fault](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1218/serial-voting-reversal-unwarranted?noredirect=1#comment4657_1218)." We can't see other people's voting history, only their reputation changes, so maybe you can see something we can't.

Comment: @uhoh Yes I see now and I would like to see the details.

Comment: @uhoh honestly, after meeting you I clicked your username and read a bunch of good answers from you. Had to have given you like +50. Surprised I didn't get flagged. Had no idea this was even a rule.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I've done that kind of thing too in the past, "SE euphoria". I'm not sure there is an articulated rule of exactly how many votes in what amount of time on how few users, but probably one of the problems that the algorithm tries to address is people gaming the system, either users up-voting each other, or users creating a 2nd ID and up-voting themselves. Anti-gaming is the reason that each time I add a bounty to the same question I have to double it, which gets expensive. https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/864/12102 and https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/889/12102

Comment: We probably have an issue in this community too with a smaller set of highly active question answering users than the larger communities.  So if someone just upvoted all the newest answered questions it would fall on a small number of folks.

Comment: @uhoh ohhh amount of votes in a timeperiod! Thank god you go into such detail ;). No way it was more than 1 vote per 10-15 minutes hehe.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I got suspended from Physics .SE for up voting to much on 1 account. I like to give out lots of up votes and got burned for target up voting. Everyone is a possible target IDK. but the idea is not to have a pattern of voting, but isn't that a pattern?

Comment: @muze chill then. Ive had 6 beers but im not soing the same.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, there are a few question-answerers with large vote-intercepting cross-sections. It's purely kinematics, statistical mechanics, etc.

Comment: To make the issue worse, there are several **badges that seem to encourage serial voting**.  Civic Duty: Vote 300 or more times.  Electorate: Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more total votes are on questions.  Sportsmanship: Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score.  Suffrage: Use 30 votes in a day.  Vox Populi:  Use the maximum 40 votes in a day.  It certainly gives a mixed message.

Comment: @DrSheldon I have been suspended for irregular up voting but not here though. I was helped and guided on this matter, and they gave me the benefit of a doubt.

Comment: @OrganicMarble network-wide I lost about 2k rep today for *user removed*. As far as I know it's not related to serial up voting, just curious if you saw anything similar.

Comment: Yes, I lost about 500 here and a smaller amount on ask unbuntu. There are extensive discussions in the main meta and ask ubuntu meta, seems like some high rep people deleted their accounts.